# Why does setup:di:compile fail on PHP 7 but not on PHP 5.6?

Tags: magento2, setup-di-compile

Running: `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` (also happens on Debian Stretch)
`Magento 2.1.1`
`PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3` (cli) ( NTS )

Magento installed and DB set up etc.

I run:

```
rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/composer_home/cache/*
chmod 777 var -R
chmod 777 pub -R
php -d memory_limit=2048M bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Then I get the error:

```
Compilation was started.
Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 1 sec 44.0 MiBPHP Fatal error:  Cannot use Cminds\Marketplace\Model\Fields as Fields because the name is already in use in /var/www/html/app/code/Cminds/Marketplace/Controller/Adminhtml/Suppliers/Deletecustomfield.php on line 7
Segmentation fault
```

On `PHP 5.6.27 (cli) (built: Oct 23 2016 11:47:58)` I do not get this error and compilation happens successfully.

1. Does anyone know why the PHP version would cause this?
2. Adding -vvv does nothing (as far as I can tell, no extra logging in /var/log), is there a way I can get more information relating to the error?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Upgrade PHP, there was a bug in the earlier versions of 7.0.x causing this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't realise the Ubuntu repos contain a buggy PHP release. I added ppa:ondrej/php and used his PHP release. Then it worked. Dankjewel Daniel ;)

Comment: Not necessarily a PHP 7 bug. You could get segmentation fault errors if you have PHP code issues, too. See PHP error log to see if you're getting any PHP fatal errors.